# What is strongly-typed View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

What is strongly-typed View in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is an aspx page that derives from [`System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470798.aspx). It is said that this view is strongly typed to the type `TModel`. As a consequence to this there's a [Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492184(v=VS.100).aspx) property inside this view which is of type `TModel` and allows you to directly access properties of the model like this:

```
<%= Model.Name %>
<%= Model.Age %>
```

where as if your aspx page derived from [`System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.aspx) you would need to pull values from `ViewData` the view no longer knows about the `TModel` type:

```
<%= (string)ViewData["Name"] %>
<%= (int)ViewData["Age"] %>
```

or even worse:

```
<%= ((SomeModelType)ViewData["model"]).Name %>
```

and there's no compile time safety in such code.

Notice also that there's the [`ViewUserControl<TModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505223.aspx) counterpart for strongly typed partials (ASCX).

Answer (score 12):

Strongly typed views are used for rendering specific types of model objects, instead of using  the general ViewData structure. By specifying the type of data, you get access to IntelliSense for the model class.

Comment: what if the View uses the fields or properties of multiple Model Classes?

Comment: @AbidAli Make a seperate "view model" whose members are instances of the multiple model classes. For example, if you have `ModelA`, `ModelB`, and `ModelC`, then you'd have a view model that is: `public class MyViewModel { public ModelA ModelA { get; set; } public ModelB ModelB { get; set; } public ModelC ModelC { get; set; }}`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a view which specifies the type of the object passed to it as its model - so instead of a view that inherits from `ViewPage`, it inherits from `ViewPage<T>` where `T` is the type of the model.