# Calling .NET Class Library (DLL) in a HTML page

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net

I have a HTML page and I need it to invoke some methods defined by a .NET Class Library project.

For example, there is a list of blocked websites defined by the network administrator. When the user accesses a blocked website, a HTML error page is automatically thrown. I want this error page, when loaded, to call the "SomeFunction()" method, which is defined in the class library project.

Is that possible?

Comment: it maybe easier to implement this at firewall level.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. To begin with, you can't implement a DLL using javascript.

Comment: Maybe the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript) will help.

Comment: @Icarus: Ok, didn't know that. Please focus on my scenario: a html page that when loaded calls a function defined by a .net class library. Thats it

Comment: What server are you hosting it on, ASP.net, PHP? It is impossible to achieve, if you do not use any kind of server.

Comment: @Tung Everything in the post you mentioned is about .net environment. My page is in html, trying to call a method inside a .net class library.

Comment: @dotTutorials it runs on Apache, only html

Comment: If you really must have javascript invoke anything from a DLL you will need to write a COM wrapper around the dll, install the dll, wrapper, .NET framework on the client machine, tweak security so javascript can invoke the call, than call the COM wrapper from javascript..lots of work and likely not what you're asking.

Comment: And, and alternative may be to look into Silverlight http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav

Comment: @PeskyGnat wow, didn't imagine how toilsome this is. Is there another way? I've heard about ajax and json but don't know if is possible working only with html

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you are requesting. You can not, however; directly call a .dll file from JavaScript. If you want to call a function from a .NET dll in JavaScript, you will have to pass some parameters to your server and then get a response.

My best guess would be, that you will have to use JSON and ajax to do just that job.
I would suggest you to look further into ASP.Net. [Here's a good start.](http://www.asp.net/)

Comment: your link doesn't seem to work

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me at the time. According to http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/asp.net.html it is also up and running. Are you still having trouble reaching the site?

Comment: nevermind, connection issues, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC? You can search for "Strongly Typed Views", in this case you can call these methods.

See this: [Strongly Typed Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896544/what-is-strongly-typed-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: no, it's only html, hosted by Apache. Is it possible?

Comment: In this case you can't use views... sorry but i don't know how to help you.