# MVC Movie Tutorial And Strongly Typed Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to follow the MVC Movies tutorial and understand everything so far. Im just a little confused on something regarding the strongly typed views.

I think i understand their purpose. Im just unsure how they would work in a real life secenario outside of this tutorial.

For example a strongly typed view that needs to get data from more than one table.

Lets say the movies application in the tutorial has another table called comments for example.

And on each movie we want to display the comments.

How can a strongly typed view access two different models (i presume it cant). What is the correct way to approach this situation.

(i have searched and cant really find an answer i understand - a comment in this thread [What is strongly-typed View in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896544/what-is-strongly-typed-view-in-asp-net-mvc) touched on the subject but i dont really understand his answer)

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine for a strongly-typed model (a "view model", in this case) to draw data from multiple models.  A simple example might look something like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in your controller, you can populate each of those collections however you see fit:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel();
    model.Employees = // ... fetch from database.
    model.Jobs = // ... fetch from database.

    return View(model);
}
```

Now, in your view, you can access them like so:

```
@model SomeViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employees)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Jobs)
```

I don't remember the MVC Movie tutorial very well, so this may already have been covered.  If not, the next step is to create a display templates for each of these, in order for the collection to be displayed correctly.

To do that, follow these steps:

1. Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\DisplayTemplates`).
2. Create a strongly-typed view in that directory with the name that matches your model (i.e. in the example above you would make two views, which would be called `Employee.cshtml` and `Job.cshtml`, respectively).

Then those templates could look something like this:

Employee.cshtml:

```
@model Employee

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

Job.cshtml:

```
@model Job

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

The display templates, and their counterpart editor templates, are smart enough to know how to handle collections, so these templates will be invoked for each member of the collection, rendering the content of the template for each item.

For what it's worth, I vividly remember how confusing it was trying to figure out what a view model actually is, when I started off with MVC.  From the way the official Entity Framework tutorials were initially setup, it didn't make it clear (at least, to me).  So, with that in mind, have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878956/729541) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160649/729541) because both answers cleared up quite a lot for me.

Comment: Thanks very much - i am still here and do appreciate your time. Just giving it a good read trying to get my head around it.

Comment: @loveforfire33 You're welcome, and there's no rush. There's a lot of different concepts there.

Comment: Ok, had a good read through it all its a bit of a brain melter!From what i understand i would end up with three models.

Employee,
Job, and SomeViewModel.

SomeViewModel would only have the variables i need for that specific page - say jobList.

I would then create a jobList controller in which i would select SomeViewModel as the modelclass and get the data from the db.

I would then create a strongly typed view to the SomeViewModel controller and add code similar to your example someviewmodel view code. 

Does this sound right?

Comment: @loveforfire33 `SomeViewModel would only have the variables i need for that specific page - say jobList` - this part is right.  You're also right in saying you'd end up with a minimum of 3 models.  As for the controller, this part isn't quite right.  Typically, you create controllers based on grouped functionality they provide.  So for example, you might have a `CustomerController` that handles displaying lists of customers and also view the details of those customers.

Comment: @loveforfire33 Each customer could have multiple orders, but that doesn't mean you need an `OrdersController`, as the functionality to show a customer's orders makes sense to be a part of `CustomerController`.

Comment: So would i still specify the controllers modelclass to someViewModel and extend someViewModel to have all of the attributes i would need for various other actions on the controller?

Comment: @loveforfire33 You typically have one view model per view.  The idea is that view model encompasses all of the data your view needs to be displayed correctly.

Comment: @loveforfire33 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41235/discussion-between-john-h-and-loveforfire33)

Answer (score 0):

When I started with MVC got confused about the strongly typed views concept too!

Then, and after some punches in the forehead, I realized that the idea of creating a view bound to a model doesn't necessarily means that model is gonna represent a table from your database or an entity from your mapper.

The thing is that in a model you can group any necessary data types you may need in your views so when the model is accessed in the view you have all the data you need in a strongly-typed way.

Taking the example of the movies you said the model I would create for my strongly typed view would be something like:

```
public class MovieModel
{
  public int MovieId {get; set;}
  public string MovieName {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<CommentModel> MovieComments {get; set;}
}

public class CommentModel
{
  public int CommentId {get; set;}
  public int CommentText {get; set;}
}
```

So in my view I could cycle through the comments of my movie like this:

```
@model MovieModel

foreach(var comment in Model.MovieComments)
{
    //Do somthing with your comments   
}
```

Of course filling your MovieModel on your controller first, let say on the edit action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var _Movie = Movie.GetMovieById(id);
    var _Comments = Comments.GetCommentsByMovieId(id);

    var _MovieModel = new MovieModel();
    _MovieModel.MovieId = _Movie.MovieId;
    _MovieModel.MovieName = _Movie.MovieName;
    _MovieModel.MovieComments = (from Comment _Comment in _Comments select new
    CommentModel{ CommentId = _Comment.CommentId , CommentText = _Comment.CommentText }).ToList();

    return View(_MovieModel);
}
```

Of course you could use directly the comments entity on your MovieModel class so you won't need a CommentModel and it would be something like:

```
public class MovieModel
    {
      public int MovieId {get; set;}
      public string MovieName {get; set;}
      public IEnumerable<Comment> MovieComments {get; set;}
    }
```

And your action like:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var _Movie = Movie.GetMovieById(id);
        var _Comments = Comments.GetCommentsByMovieId(id);

        var _MovieModel = new MovieModel();
        _MovieModel.MovieId = _Movie.MovieId;
        _MovieModel.MovieName = _Movie.MovieName;
        _MovieModel.MovieComments = _Comments;

        return View(_MovieModel);
    }
```

Ending up with only one model and data from different tables on the same strongly typed view as in the previous case, although some may say you are violating some  MVC concepts by doing it this way is completely possible....

Hope to be helpful

Comment: There's no need to use `foreach` in your views when you don't need to.  Utilising the `Html.*` helpers keeps your views clean and free of logic (which is what they should be).

Comment: Your right, however I just wanted to be clear on how your data is strongly typed within the Model object in the view