# DropDownListFor with ViewBag getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Controller:

```
using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
    {                
      var item = session.Query<CarModel>().ToList();
      ViewBag.Modas = item;
      return View();
    }
```

View:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Modelis.model_name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">                    
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Modelis.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Modas, "Id", "model_name"), "--Select Cars--")                       
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller(submition part):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Transport item)
{
    try
    {
        using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(item);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And I get error on submit:

**Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

And I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: Can you provide the controller method used for the submit. Specifically what does the method signature look like? What does the code look like that is throwing the exception?

Comment: You aren't specifying a model in your controller, so any reference to `model` is going to be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your submitted code, it seems you are using **Strongly Typed View** of MVC. In this case you should supply model to your view.
You are returning view without supplied or assigning a model. Hence your view has model as null. Please supply the model and check the execution.

```
using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
    {                
      var item = session.Query<CarModel>().ToList();
      ViewBag.Modas = item;
      // Either set the model like .... ViewData.Model = new YOUR_MODEL_CLASS();
     // OR return your model by view constructor like.. return View(new YOUR_MODEL_CLASS());
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: How can I do it any of your suggestions?

Comment: Well if you are doing something like ...  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => ...... then it requires a model to refer on the view page. You must have a strongly typed view. Hence you should intialize your model and assign it to the view from controller action method.

Comment: If you don't know what is Strongly Typed view in MVC then refer this post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896544/what-is-strongly-typed-view-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: But if I remove DropDownListPart with model everything else works, @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lic_plate... and etc works. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Html.LableFor will work fine because it doesn't requires instance of the model. It just access the property name by Type. You have to assign correct instance of model to the view